# PubSub in typescript without `any` type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to implement simple PubSub pattern using typescript. Now it looks like this:

```
type CallbackFunc<T = any> = (arg: T) => void;

export class PubSub {
  private events: Record<string, CallbackFunc> = {};
  private static instance: PubSub;

  static getInstance(): PubSub {
    if (PubSub.instance) {
      return PubSub.instance;
    } else {
      PubSub.instance = new PubSub();

      return PubSub.instance;
    }
  }

  publish(eventName: string, value: any): void {
    this.events[eventName](value);
  }

  subscribe(eventName: string, handler: CallbackFunc): void {
    this.events[eventName] = handler;
  }
}
```

What do I want to achieve is to avoid using `any` type. How do I do this?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wz7ykw) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: But how would you use this without `any`? It seems `events` will be able to hold any kind of callback, so `any` will probably be the common denominator...

Comment: @MathiasFalkenberg replace with unknown :D

Comment: @wonderflame You are still using any as a type definition for arguments

Comment: Yes, but it still can infer the type. You can change it to unknown. Should work as well

Comment: @MathiasFalkenberg this is exactly what I am thinking about, without using any I cannot achieve what I need to. But I am asking the question because I think that I am missing something out.

Comment: @wonderflame replacing `any` with `unknown` doesn't work

Comment: @wonderflame it seems like there is no difference between your approach and my code

Comment: There is. your approach gives: `Record<string, CallbackFunc<any>>`. Mine gives:`{event1: (myArgument: string) => void; event2: (myArgument: number) => void; event3: (myArgument: {foo: string;bar: number;}) => void;}`

Comment: @wonderflame You are right, but actually, it still doesn't fit. May be I was not very informative. Let's imagine that these callbacks are created outside of this code. They are not defined in the scope of the `events` variable, they are added in it automatically by another function. I am going to describe the whole usecase to elaborate on the problem

Comment: @IvanFrolov can you explain what exactly you want to achieve? If you just want to get rid of the `any` you can replace it with `unknown`.

Comment: @IvanFrolov there is nothing inherently wrong with using `any` if there is in fact no better type that covers your use-case. And in this case it seems you want to accept callbacks of any type. I do agree with @wonderflame that it is hard to see what the goal here is. Using `any` will prevent type checking from giving you useful feedback on potentially wrong code.

For the updated example, replacing 'any' with 'unknown' does seem to be the correct solution, since this particular piece of code does not need to access the value, and hence doesn't care about the type

Comment: Also, for the updated example, it would seem you no longer need the generic type at all, but could simply define `type CallbackFunc = (arg: unknown) => void;`